# Converting a Google Sheets formula to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am converting a Google Sheet into an HTML page and am running into an issue with a particular formula:

`=(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(((SUMPRODUCT(--(C10>=B24:B32),(C10-B24:B32),(D24:D32-D23:D31))))), 1, 1))+C18`

I inherited this formula and *do not* understand it at all. For the sake of expediency, I have an object with a bunch of keys in it. Basically like this:

```
let sheet = {
    c10: 10,
    c18: 2,
    d24: 2,
    ...
}
```

Which leads me to creating the getter for this calculation. I am so lost. I've looked for an online tool, but have come up empty handed.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample spreadsheet that uses that formula?

Answer (score 3):

This formula won't translate well, as it relies on vector operations, which JavaScript doesn't have common support for. Assuming a suitable vector implementation, the formula itself can be described, though without context, its intended usage and meaning cannot. To deconstruct sheets formulae yourself, I recommend placing any subexpression you don't understand in its own cell to see what it does.

After a few of the expressions below is a name in parentheses. Rather than repeating this expression in later formulae, this name is used.

- `C10>=B24:B32`:

  This creates a vector of boolean values, `FALSE` for all values in B that exceed C10, `TRUE` for all values that are less than or equal. To see this, try setting a cell  to `=ARRAYFORMULA(C10>=B24:B32)`. In parallel processing, this is a common way to create a mask for a vector operation, which is used to exclude certain values from the computation (which is its function here, as will be seen below).
- `--(C10>=B24:B32)` (`pos`)

  A single negative turns a boolean to an integer, but with negated logical value. A double negative turns a boolean into an integer with equivalent logical value (`TRUE` to 1, `FALSE` to 0). In other words, this is a vector with 0 wherever the corresponding `B` exceeds `C`, and 1 wherever `B` is ≤ `C`. In Javascript, a [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) performs the same function. Modify the previous cell formula, adding negations one at a time to see how they affect the results.
- `C10-B24:B32` (`cSubB`)

  This is a vector of differences between the scalar C10 and vector components of B. In other words, `[c-b[0], c-b[1], c-b[2], ...]`.
- `D24:32-D23:31` (`Δ`)

  Subtracting adjacent components gives you the deltas, or differences between components. This could mean many things, such as a "rate" of some type (the 1st derivative), or the [method of differences](https://brilliant.org/wiki/method-of-differences/) (which is a 1st derivative in disguise, but without using calculus). Try `=ARRAYFORMULA(D24:32-D23:31)` in a sheet to see it in action. With a suitable vector class, it might look like `d.slice(1) - d.slice(0,-1)`.
- `SUMPRODUCT(pos, cSubB, Δ)` (`sumprod`)

  [`SUMPRODUCT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294?hl=en) calculates the componentwise products of vectors (i.e. `x * y = [x[0]*y[0], x[1]*y[1], ...]`). Multiplying a mask vector (here, `pos`) by another vector (here, `cSubB`) selects values from the other vector. Since `pos` is precisely 0 when `B[i] > C`, multiplying will exclude the negative values of `C-B` and keep the non-negative values. The deltas are also then multiplied, with the mask still applying (the why of this last operation comes down to meaning, and can't be determined by examining the formula).

  Javascript doesn't have anything like `SUMPRODUCT` as a single operation, but it could be constructed using vector and array operations, such as [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). A sequence of Javascript expressions to perform the same operations might be:

  ```
  let pos = b.map(x => +(c >= b)),
     cSubB = b.map(x => c - x),
     delta = d.slice(1).sub(d.slice(0,-1)),
     prod = pos.mul(cSubB).mul(delta),
     sumprod = prod.reduce((a,b)=>a+b, 0);
  ```

  Note that `SUMPRODUCT` is implemented as `pos.mul(cSubB).mul(delta).reduce((a,b)=>a+b, 0)`, with the other expressions being the subexpressions of `SUMPRODUCT`.

  If vectors were to support indexing on collections (i.e. the index operation/[slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_slicing) accepted a list of indices, rather than just a scalar, similar to how [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#index-19) accept [slices](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/expressions.html#slicings) in Python, or in just about any array programming language (such as [`{` in J](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d520.htm) (warning: madness))), you could take another approach using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

  ```
  let idxs = b.map((x,i) => [i, c >= x]).filter([i, keep] => keep).map([i,_] => i),
      delta = d.slice(1).sub(d.slice(0,-1)),
      prod = b.slice(idxs).map(x => c - x).mul(delta.slice(idxs)),
      sumprod = prod.reduce((a,b)=>a+b, 0);
  ```
- `ARRAYFORMULA(sumprod)`

  [`ARRAYFORMULA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) evaluates an expression in an array context, allowing for array results (values that spill over into adjacent cells) and for scalar expressions to become array expressions (such as `C - B24:B32`). However, `SUMPRODUCT` already provides an array context, and it only ever returns a scalar, so it would appear to do nothing in this case. It's possible whoever wrote this formula either didn't realize `SUMPRODUCT` provided an array context, or started using `ARRAYFORMULA` before introducing `SUMPRODUCT` for the arithmetic expressions (as shown above, when trying out the arithmetic expressions), or had a different formula than the `SUMPRODUCT(pos, cSubB, delta)` one which required an array context for some reason.
- `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(sumprod), 1, 1)`

  An `ARRAYFORMULA` spills out into neighboring cells; which cells depend on the shape of the expression it contains. [`ARRAY_CONTAIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267036?hl=en&ref_topic=3105706) then limits this spill by restricting to the given shape. It's not explicit in the documentation, but values outside the limits are ignored. The shape of `1,1` basically means a scalar. Since the result is already a scalar, this outer expression serves no purpose in the formula.

Lastly, the result is added to `C18`, but that hardly needs mentioning.

### Postscript

A vector module is beyond the scope of this Q&A, but let me hint at some alternative approaches for componentwise operations using already existing capabilities:

```
// using indices from `a`
let aTimesB = a.map((x, i) => x * b[i]);

// using index collections
let idxs = [...Array(a.length).keys],
    cSubBTimesDelta = idxs.map(i => (c - b[i]) * (d[i+1] - d[i]));
```